# Worldmap issues in echart

Tags: javascript

I create a world map in my project using e-chart library in JavaScript, and I need to take the latitude and longitude on click on the location on the map.Is there any possible way to get the latitude and longitude details from the map.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example

http://echarts.baidu.com/echarts2/doc/example/map4.html
(replace the population to  latitude and longitude)

This is the demon of echart maps(in English)

http://echarts.baidu.com/echarts2/doc/example-en.html